# .datepicker call inside of Durandal activate function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

I'm Composing this in a view, then trying to call .datepicker() on the result, but nothing happens.

**The compose container**

```
<div>
<!--ko compose: { model:'viewmodels/schedule', view: 'views/schedule.html', activate:true} -->
<!--/ko-->
</div>
```

**schedule.html**

```
<div class="schedule-editor">

</div>
```

**And the schedule module**

```
define([], function () {
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
    };
    return vm;

    function activate() {
        $('.schedule-editor').datepicker();
        console.log("activated schedule module");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Console logs "activated schedule module",  but the datepicker is not created.
If I go to the chrome console and run the jQuery call,
`$('.schedule-editor').datepicker();` it brings up the datepicker just fine.

The Durandal docs claim that the activate function is called after the DOM is full composed, so I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Try to put your jQuery logic into a `viewAttached` method instead of the `activate` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like nemesv mentioned you should use [viewAttached](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/) instead.

```
define([], function () {
    var vm = {
        viewAttached: viewAttached,
    };
    return vm;

    function viewAttached(view) {
        $(view).find('.schedule-editor').datepicker();
        console.log("activated schedule module");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Activate happens in the lifecycle before your model has been data-bound to the new view and before the view has been added to the dom. viewAttached happens after the view has been data-bound to your model and attached to the dom.

## **EDIT**

Durandal 2.0 has renamed `viewAttached` to `attached`

Comment: I just tested that, it worked after I changed the jquery to the original call,  doing $(view).find didn't work.  Otherwise,  works now, thanks guys

Comment: Just to remind - "viewAttached" was renamed to "attached" in durandal 2.0 so use that name instead for that version.

Answer (score 5):

There is another approach to this that stays true to the declarative UI philosophy that knockout.js and durandal are striving for.

It will allow you to declare the datepicker within the HTML like this:

```
<div class="schedule-editor" data-bind="
    jqueryui: { 
        widget: 'datepicker', 
        options: { 
            // you can set options here as per the jquery ui datepicker docs
        } 
    }">

</div>
```

Simply include the jquery ui widget bindings found in this gist: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---jqueryui-widgets

Make sure you include the above javascript after you have loaded jquery, jquery ui and knockout.

Comment: prefer this to the previous approach since it keeps the VM clean. For ui specific handling i guess it should be a custom binding which knockout too advocates?